# Why @Component, @Resource, @Service used in Jersey integrating with spring framework?

Tags: spring-mvc, jax-rs

[image]

Attached my screenshot which is entry level rest class, where used @Component. Why used @Component ?

I gone through below blog 
http://www.benchresources.net/jersey-2-x-web-service-integrating-with-spring-framework-using-annotation/

Answer (score 2):

@Component, @Resource, @Service used because you are still using spring framework application for dependency injection, specifically to link to found classes by component scan, and you want it to be able to autowire spring components as you service or dao classes